# Run report from Apex

Tags: apex, reporting, schedule

My users want more control scheduling reports.  The scheduler only offers a limited set of times and frequencies.  I know how to schedule apex scripts using System.schedule and a cron string.  Is there a way to setup a report run similarly and bypass the schedule gui limitations?  Can I initiate a report from apex?  If so, I could put it into a schedulable script and then use System.schedule.

Comment: also check out [Conga Courier](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016ZopEAE) for additional flexibility

Answer (score 2):

You can call the [Reports and Dashboards API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_intro.htm) from Apex.

Note, however, that it comes with a *wide* variety of its own [limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_limitations.htm), and what it does is returns data to your Apex code. It does not provide functionality to deliver report data to your users in email form.

Because the limits are fairly low:

> - Your org can request up to 500 synchronous report runs per hour.
> - The API supports up to 20 synchronous report run requests at a time.
>     -Your organization can request up to 1,200 asynchronous requests per hour.

it may or may not suffice for your organization's needs.

Lastly, your Apex will be responsible for deciphering and transforming the fairly complex [fact map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_fact_map.htm) data structure that's returned.